# UI doesn't render when ran using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi I have a application to test that is written in php.

It has a tree view that shows country names. When i click on it, it expands and shows states

If I do this manually, it works perfectly fine. If I use selenium and launch the browser and do the same steps using automation, the tree view never expands. It keeps on spinning.

If i pause the automation and try to do the operations manually on THAT window it never works. I am not sure how to debug this. Any pointers would be really helpful. I am using Selenium 2.34 and firefox 22 browser.

Comment: `It keeps on spinning.` Are you seeing any timeout ? or it is indefinite ? May be you can wait for sometime and then click the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Please run your test in debug mode (setting breakpoints after the click on the tree expand), that is a good way to start de-bugging. If it runs with breakpoints , try introducing page waits (for expected elements) .

Comment: I have tried all of this. Its not wait issue. I think its sth to do with the way selenium launches browser. If i put a breakpoint and try to click on the UI element(selenium launched browser) it never works. This is not timeout issue. This happens only with browser istance launched by selenium. If i launch it manually it works fine.